# Comparing form input to JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a popup modal that displays on page load that has the following form in it:

```
<form class="enterForm">
    <label class="modalFields" id="userName" style="display: none;">
        <span>user Number :</span>
        <input type="text" name="userNum" placeholder="User Number" required/>
    </label>
</form>

<label>
    <span>&nbsp;</span>  
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submitButton">
    <input type="hidden" id="hiddenInput">
</label>
```

And on user submission of the form, I want to hit a certain API via an AJAX call, which returns a JSON that looks like:

```
{  
   "results":[  
      {  
         "person":{  
            "firstName":"John",
            "lastName":"Smith"
         },
         "userNumber":"12345"
      }
   ]
}
```

If the userNumber matches the value that the user submitted, I then want to update the nav bar to say the person's first name.  In terms of process flow I want it to go: user types in user number -> submits form -> AJAX call hits API -> checks to see if user input matches userNumber value in JSON --> if match, selects the firstName value and updates it in the nav bar.  How could I go about achieving this?

Comment: Would you mind posting the javascript client-side + api endpoint server-side code you have so far?

Answer (score 2):

Considering you know how to do AJAX calls and you're using an API, integrating jQuery to facilitate the thing shouldn't be too hard (if it is, I included additional information after the solution).

### Solution

**JavaScript**

```js
//On form submit
$('#enterForm').submit(function(){
  var userNum = $('[name="userNum"]').val();

  //AJAX call to your API
  $.ajax({
    url: 'myAPICall.php',
    /* data: {userNumber: userNum}, //If necessary */
    success: function(data) {
        // Note: this code is only executed when the AJAX call is successful.
        if(data.results.userNumber == userNum){
            $('#navBarFirstName').text(data.results.person.firstName);
        }
    },
    error: function (err) {
      //If the AJAX call fails, this will be executed.
      console.error(err); 
    }
    dataType: 'JSON'
  });

  return false; //Prevents the page refresh if an action is already set on the form.
});
```

### Explanation

You use jQuery to bind a function (event listener) to the `submit` event of your form.

When the `submit` event is triggered, the function runs:

- It gets the value of your DOMElement with the name attribute "*userNum*"
- It makes an AJAX call to your API (with/without the userNum value, you choose if you want to check that on the server side or not)
- On success, (when the call is done successfully), it updates the navbar content using `.text()` with the *firstName* attribute of your JSON response.

---

### Including jQuery

You can integrate jQuery by including the script within your HTML page. You can either [download it](https://jquery.com/download/) or use a [CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery/):

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js">
/* Don't put your code in here it won't be parsed */
</script>

<!-- the following tag could also be <script src="link/to/your/script.js"></script> -->
<script>
 /* Your actual script */
</script>
```

Make sure to put this line before your actual javascript file containing the script written above, otherwise jQuery won't be initialized and the script won't work.

Comment: This is a great answer, but I'm having some issues with one of the lines

`$('#navBarFirstName').text(data.results.person.firstName)` is returning the following error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined"

Comment: Then the issue is within your JSON object. debug it using `console.log()` to see its structure and adapt the `data.results.person.firstName` in my code snippet to whatever is the right thing within your JSON object. My example was based on the JSON object your provided in the question and might not be 100% accurate for your actual code.